# Faulty string comparison using strtok()

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char stringbuf[256] = "add joe smith 120120120";
   char* cmd = strtok(stringbuf, " ");

   if (cmd == "add")
    printf("ADD command recognized!\n");
   else
    printf("UNRECOGNIZABLE COMMAND!\n");

   system("PAUSE");
}
```

I've used the breakpoint to check what each variable holds.
cmd has "add" yet, it's printing "UNRECOGNIZABLE COMMAND!".

What is wrong?

Comment: You can't compare strings like that. Look at `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `(cmd == "add")`, you're comparing two pointers to characters, you're **not** comparing strings.

If you want to compare strings in C++ code, use `std::string`. If you want to write C-style code, use `strcmp`.